# JsonSerializer has no more effect since guice-DI came into play

Tags: java, jersey, guice

I´m about bulding a small blueprint-app for REST-services that use Hibernate (through JPA). In order to separate the layers more cleanly and have better testability, I later decided to introduce guice for DI.
Before that step the application worked fine overall, but after I rearranged everything there is one thing left that is not running anymore, that is: the serialization/deserialization of my POJOs java.util.Date fields.
The serialization just returns the usual `toString()` from the `java.util.Date` objects.

I couldn´t find any error yet. There is no stacktrace and I crawled up and down the web to get any clue, without success so far.
The `@JsonSerialize(using=JsonDateSerializer.class)` and `@JsonDeserialize(using=JsonDateDeSerializer.class)` annotations are no more used, that means, the methods inside the implementing classes are not called.
I have also tried the `@JsonSerialize(using=JsonDateSerializer.class, as java.util.Date)` variant, with no positive effect.

Below are the components, that make up the interesting parts (at least I hope so).
All classes are within the same package. For the sake of brevity, I tried to leave out some irrelevant parts.

Would be great if someone could give me a hint for further debugging.

Thanks a lot!

*EDIT: I found a possible solution to my problem, but not the explanation why the `@JsonSerialize` stopped working. I used an `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateAdapter.class)` and implemented the marshal/unmarshal methods*

## pom.xml

```
...
<properties>
    <jersey-version>1.18.1</jersey-version>
</properties>       
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-version}</version>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-guice</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice-persist</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
```

## web.xml

```
...
<listener>
    <listener-class>the.package.ApplicationContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<filter>
    <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>       
...
```

## the POJO

```
package the.package;
import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonDeserialize;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize;

@XmlRootElement
@Entity
@Table(name = "vacation", catalog = "vacations")
public class Vacation implements java.io.Serializable { 
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2855180550795143900L;
    private Long id;
    private Date start;
    private String status;

    public Vacation() {
    }

    public Vacation(Date start, String status) {
        this.start = start;
        this.status = status;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "start", nullable = false, length = 19)
    @JsonSerialize(using=JsonDateSerializer.class)
    public Date getStart() { 
        return this.start;
    }

    @JsonDeserialize(using=JsonDateDeSerializer.class)
    public void setStart(Date start) {
        this.start = start;
    }   
    ...
}
```

## the serializer

```
package the.package;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerator;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonProcessingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonSerializer;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializerProvider;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class JsonDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date>{
    private DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");    
    @Override
    public void serialize(Date date, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException { 
        String formattedDate = fmt.print(new DateTime(date));
        gen.writeString(formattedDate);
    }   
}
```

## the deserializer

```
package the.package;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonProcessingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationContext;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonDeserializer;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class JsonDateDeSerializer extends JsonDeserializer<Date>{
    private DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");    
    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        DateTime dt = fmt.parseDateTime(jp.getText());      
        return dt.toDate();
    } 
}
```

## the context listener

```
package the.package;
import com.google.inject.Guice;
import com.google.inject.Injector;
import com.google.inject.persist.PersistFilter;
import com.google.inject.persist.jpa.JpaPersistModule;
import com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceServletContextListener;
import com.google.inject.servlet.ServletModule;
import com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.core.ResourceConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.servlet.GuiceContainer;

public class ApplicationContextListener extends GuiceServletContextListener {
    @Override
    protected Injector getInjector() {
        final ResourceConfig rc = new PackagesResourceConfig("the.package");
        return Guice.createInjector(new ServletModule() {
            @Override
            protected void configureServlets() {
                install(new JpaPersistModule("sessionVacations"));              
                bind(IUserDao.class).to(UserDao.class);
                bind(IVacationDao.class).to(VacationDao.class);             
                for (Class<?> resource : rc.getClasses()) {
                    bind(resource);
                }
                filter("/*").through(PersistFilter.class);              
                serve("/*").with(GuiceContainer.class);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

## the service

```
package the.package;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import com.google.inject.Inject;

@Path("/vacation")
public class VacationService {
    @Inject
    private IVacationDao dao;

    @GET
    @Path("/get/{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Vacation getVacation(@PathParam("id") int id) {      
        return dao.loadVacationById(id); 
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/list")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Vacation> getVacations(@QueryParam("userid") int userid) {  
        if (userid != 0) {
            return dao.loadAllVacationsByUser(userid);
        } else {
            return dao.loadAllVacations(); 
        }
    }   
}
```

## the DAOs interface

```
package the.package;
import java.util.List;

public interface IVacationDao {
    public abstract Vacation loadVacationById(long id);
    public abstract List<Vacation> loadAllVacations();
    public abstract List<Vacation> loadAllVacationsByUser(int userid);
}
```

## the DAO

```
package the.package;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Join;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;
import com.google.inject.Inject;

public class VacationDao implements IVacationDao {

    @Inject
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public Vacation loadVacationById(long id) {
        Vacation vacation = em.find(Vacation.class, new Long(id));
        return vacation;
    }   

    ...
}
```

Comment: This is an excellent post, unfortunately I don't know jersey well enough to help you. But hopefully my +1 will help you get more attention

Comment: maybe i'm missing something, but i don't see any jackson module registrations. are you doing that in code you didn't post?